# How do I link CoC to the correct Python interpreter?

Tags: neovim, plugin-coc

I just installed Ubuntu linux on my laptop and made sure to install python.

After installing Python, I type the command `python3 --version` and found that I got version 3.9.7, which is stored in the `/usr/bin/` directory.

However, when I manually check the directory contents in `/usr/bin` I find that I also have a Python 3.10 directory, but paid little attention to this.

Instead of re-installing gvim, which is may usual go to vim distribution, I decided to install Neovim.

I just successfully install Conqueror of Command (CoC), but noticed that it linked to a Python 3.10.0 interpreter.  I can only guess that it sees the Python 3.10 directory in `/usr/bin/`, but it should instead point to the `/usr/bin/Python3` directory.

How can I manually set the interpreter in CoC?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "coc is linked to python 3.10"? If I'm not mistaken coc doesn't require python. Are you referring to [coc-python](https://github.com/neoclide/coc-python)? In this case have you checked [this issue](https://github.com/neoclide/coc-python/issues/55) and the `python.setInterpreter` setting?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 2):

I use the `:CocConfig` command to edit the `coc-settings.json` file and make sure the `python.pythonPath` is set correctly:

Here is a excerpt of my `coc-settings.json` file to set the interpreter to Python36 on the Windows platform.

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "C:\\Python36_x64\\python.exe",
    "python.formatting.provider": "black",
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hmm, this does not seem to fix the issue.  Now when I start NeoVim on a Pythoin file it asks me which interpreter I want to use and gives me a list of options.  Any idea why it is behaving this way?

Answer (score 0):

You use the following lines in your `.vimrc` or in your `init.vim` in case you use neovim.

```
let g:python_host_prog= '/usr/bin/python'
let g:python3_host_prog= '/usr/bin/python3'
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Some explanation around _why_ this solves the problem would improve the answer (you can [edit] to add more details). Also, note that this becomes somewhat platform/programmer specific (not all `python`s are in `/usr/bin`, and you may want to use a venv-installed python). Another option might be something like `exepath('python')` or `exepath('python3')`